# Resolving a string with dot notation to a deep object property javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object that looks like this:

```
var object = {
   property: {
      deeper: {
          deepProperty: '1234'
      }
   }
}
```

I want to write a function that parses strings with dots in them into their appropriate deeply nested object value:

```
function prop(str) {
    // Should return the nested object value based on the string
}
```

For example:

```
prop('property.deeper.deepProperty')
// Should return: '1234'
```